# Create associative multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I have 3 variables, each one holding a different information and send values from a text file dynamicaly. I want to put them in a Associative multi-dimensional array.

let's say :

```
$product sends car, truck, train, etc.
$price sends 1000, 3000,  1500, etc.
$year  sends 1997, 1980, 2008, etc.
```

How to create a function which generates an array as follow, when i execute print_r(myarray):

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [product] => car [price] => 1000 [year] => 1997 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product] => truck [price] => 3000 [year] => 1980 )
[2] => Array ( [product] => train [price] => 1500 [year] => 2008 )) and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:
[Define 2D array with loops in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015878/define-2d-array-with-loops-in-php)